# how to parse logs dynamically using logstash

Tags: logstash

I am logging to logstash
my logs are in the following format:

```
timestamp  key=val key2=val2 ..<a list of key=val>.. [log-level] the rest of the message
```

example:

```
17:21:20.470 pid=<0.20592.0> app=myapp  key1=val.1 key2=val/2 [info] my message blabla
```

I would like to parse them to this format:

```
 {
     "timestamp" => "17:21:20.470",
     "pid" => "<0.20592.0>"
     "app" => myapp
     "key1" => "val.1"
     "key2" => "val/2"
     "level" => "info"
     "message" => "my message blabla"
   }
```

note: my `key=val` aren't known in advance, I would like to parse them dynamically

here is my configuration

```
input { stdin { } }  

filter {

}
 output { stdout { codec => rubydebug  }}
```

what should my filter be?

Comment: You could use grok to extract the part with the key=val, then use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-filters-kv.html) on that part.

Comment: how can I use grok to parse key=val dynamically? the key names arent known in advance, neither the amount of keys

Comment: You grab all the key=val with grok in order to have a field like this: `key1=val.1 key2=val/2`. Then you give this field to the kv filter, which extract multiple key/values.